# How to integrate Olingo(Odata) in Java SpringBoot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, odata, olingo

Can anyone please help me on how to integrate Olingo (Odata) in a Springboot Java Appln.
I'm pretty new to Spring boot and have implemented one project and wanted it to convert to Oling (Odata).

I have gone through various resources but with a bunch of different approaches not sure how to do it the correct way.
Please let me know if some has worked on it and can guide me.

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2McOiC-YEp253EQCnSHfzIJwUAY_6Ym/view?usp=sharing) to the project on which I applied spring-boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to integrate OlingoJPA there are a couple of things you will have to do

1. Implement `JPAServiceFactory` and `initializeODataJPAContext`, basically this is about [defining the persistence unit and entity manager](https://github.com/shivasaxena/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/blob/master/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/src/main/java/com/metalop/code/samples/olingo/springbootolingo2sampleproject/utils/JPAServiceFactory.java)
2. Then you can create a [Spring Boot Configuration](https://github.com/shivasaxena/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/blob/master/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/src/main/java/com/metalop/code/samples/olingo/springbootolingo2sampleproject/configuration/OlingoConfig.java) to mount your OData endpoint and initialize the `EntityManagerFactory`
3. Then you can point to your database [here](https://github.com/shivasaxena/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/blob/master/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/src/main/resources/application.properties)
4. An finally you can [define the JPA entities](https://github.com/shivasaxena/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/tree/master/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project/src/main/java/com/metalop/code/samples/olingo/springbootolingo2sampleproject/entity) you want your service to expose

The full Spring Boot + JPA project sample is located [Github](https://github.com/shivasaxena/spring-boot-olingo2-sample-project). Feel free to go though it, raise an issue or submit a Pull request for impalements

Comment: Thanks Shiva, this helped.

Comment: Thanks @Shifali ! Please feel free to contribute to the github code and accept the answer if it solved your question.